# Standalone Python web server and/or nginx

Tags: python, nginx, webserver, tornado, bottle

So I've done some reading about Python web frameworks (or servers?), mostly [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) and [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/) but also [FAPWS3](http://www.fapws.org/), and there are still some grey areas.

First, these three web frameworks are all said to be fast, yet they all include a web server written in Python (except FAPWS3) which should be put behind nginx/Apache. Isn't this reducing the performance? I mean, we know that Python is much slower than C, why not only use nginx, or at worst, only the included Python web server?

Comment: Why would you put the web servers behind another?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's part of the question.

Comment: You claim that they "should" be put behind another web server, yet you've provided no reasoning or evidence for such.

Comment: Application servers are usually slow at generating responses (even static material). A common setup is to have a fast HTTP server in front of a bunch of app servers. Also, app servers lack a lot of extra functionality of an http server like Apache or nginx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of, Tornado and FAPWS3 are web servers, while Bottle is a web framework. Those belong to completely different categories.

Web frameworks are usually run as a [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) server behind a HTTP ("web") proxy. The HTTP server included in most frameworks is only there for fast development and deployment and easy deployment on sites where high efficiency doesn't matter.

The idea is basically that the HTTP Server (Apache/Lighttpd/Nginx/Tornado/FAPWS3 etc) is very good at understanding HTTP and serving static files from the disk. The dynamic content on the other hand is generated by a Python server using a web framework like Bottle/Flask/web.py/Pylons/etc. The document produced by the web framework is then sent back to the HTTP server over WSGI, put in a HTTP Response and sent to the client.

Comment: Thank you! When you say that the dynamic content is generated by a Python server using a framework, wouldn't it be faster for the framework to directly send the response over WSGI instead of running a Python server? Or is it the way WSGI works?

Comment: @seriousdev: WSGI does not specify how the WSGI application is run. It is the WSGI container that controls that.